# Need help with Alpha Transparency

Tags: texturing, node-editor, transparency

[image: Texture and Blender Scene]

In the attached image there is a alpha texture which is used on that kitchen asset (forgot name :p) and it occupies that whole layer, i want to use the material in a way where the area excepting alpha map can be used as seperate material like a grey plastic, that Bosch logo is same but i duped that part of mesh which occupied Bosch logo and after duping, i applied seperate material, so that i can use the area except that logo as red metal.

Comment: You can use a Mix Shader Node and set the Mix Factor to be the Alpha from your Texture Image. Image Texture coordinates can come from an Empty for ease of placement, scale etc. Search for Blender Decal tutorials.

Comment: @rob you should put that as an answer, not a comment